# Proving the interior of a dual cone is the set of vectors whose inner product is strictly positive on the cone

Tags: convex-geometry, real-analysis, convexity

Apologies for posting such a simple question to mathoverflow.  I've have been stuck trying to solve this problem for some time and have posted this [same query](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167413/boyd-vandenberghe-question-2-31d-stuck-on-simple-problem-regarding-interi) to math.stackexchange (but have received no useful feedback).

$\DeclareMathOperator\cl{cl}$I am working on problem 2.31(d) in Boyd & Vandenberghe's book "[Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook)" and the question asks me to prove that the interior of a dual cone $K'$ of a convex cone $K \subseteq R^n$ is equal to the set
$$
 S = \{ y \mid y^\top x > 0 \text{ for all } x \in \cl(K) \setminus \{0\} \}.
$$

Recall that the dual cone is the set $K' = \{ y \mid y^\top x \ge 0 \text{ for all } x \in \cl(K) \setminus \{0\} \}$.

Now, for a point $z \in K'$, it is easy to show that if there exists $x \in \cl(K) \setminus \{0\}$ such that $z^\top x = 0$, then $z$ must lie on the boundary of $K'$.

So now I need only show that if $z \in K'$ and $z^\top x > 0$ for all $x \in \text{cl}(K) \backslash \{0\}$, then $z$ lies in the interior of $K'$.  Of course this means I need to find an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $z' \in D(z,\epsilon)$, we have $z'^\top x > 0$ for all $x \in \cl(K) \backslash \{0\}$.  It's here that I am stuck.

First of all, I don't know how to find such an $\epsilon$.  But even if I did, I don't know how to show that for any $z' = z + \gamma u$ with $\gamma \in (0,\epsilon)$ and $\lVert u\rVert = 1$ that

\[ z'^\top x = (z + \gamma u)^\top x > 0. \]

I am able to use the Schwartz inequality to show that

\[ z^\top x - \gamma |x| \le z^\top x + \gamma u^\top x. \]

But I can't prove the critical piece, that

\[ 0 < z^\top x - \gamma |x|. \]

One difficulty here is that because $x$ ranges over the cone $K$, its norm can be arbitrarily large.  Therefore it seems unlikely to find a single $\epsilon$ which bounds the differences of the inner products ($z^\top x$ and $z'^\top x$) for all of $x$ in $K$.

On the other hand, the statement that $S$ is the interior of $K'$ seems entirely reasonable so there should be a way to prove this.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  I am very interested to see what mathematical technologies I am missing.

Comment: TeX note: please use $\operatorname{cl}(K) \setminus \{0\}$ `\operatorname{cl}(K) \setminus \{0\}`, not $\text{cl}(K) \backslash \{0\}$ `\text{cl}(K) \backslash \{0\}`, for set difference; notice the difference in spacing.  (I also recommend, as you notice `\operatorname` for operators; here it doesn't make much difference, but notice, for example, $\operatorname{cl} K$ `\operatorname{cl} K` *versus* $\text{cl} K$ `\text{cl} K`).  I have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\cl{cl}$Something along the following lines will work: note that $z$ satisfies $z^\top x>0$ for all $x\in \cl(K)$ iff $z$ satisfies $z^\top x>0$ for all $x\in \cl(K)$ s.t. $\lVert x\rVert=1$, i.e. for all  $x\in \cl(K)\cap S^{n-1}$. Note that $U:=\cl(K)\cap S^{n-1}$ is compact, thus the function $x\mapsto z^\top x$, being a continuous function on a compact, reaches its minimum, say, $\delta>0$,  on $U$.

Next, for an arbitrary $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, take $f_y(x)=y^\top x$. Again, $\inf_{x\in U} f_y(x)$ exists, and is equal to $\delta_y$, which might be negative or positive.
Still, we can take sufficiently small $\alpha_y>0$ so that $(z+\alpha_y y)^\top x\geq 0$ for all $x\in U$.
(I leave the computation of $\alpha_y$ from $\delta$ and $\delta_y$ to you, it's not hard.)

Finally, you need to pick up enough vectors $y$ so that $z$ lies in the interior of the cone spanned by the vectors $z+\alpha_y y$ (note that these lie in $\cl(K')$ by construction).

Comment: Thanks Dima! I came up with a similar proof offline and was happy to see your answer in agreement.

The critical insight is that $z^\top x>0 \iff z^\top x / \|x\|>0.$

So this allows one to do the proof for vectors $x \in \text{cl}(K) \backslash \{0\}$ of unit length, and then extend the result to vectors with arbitrary length.
